# Java generics problem

Tags: java, generics

I'm implementing a high-order split function, which takes a collection of items to be splitted, a filter delegate which defines the boundary criteria of the split, and two ReturnDelegate, which are delegates that provides the concrete collection type of the return collections (so I don't need to fix ArrayList or HashSet in the split function, but rather, leaving the creation of the return collections to the calling code, yielding flexibility). The return is a Tuple2 class, which is basically a wrapper around two heterogeneous objects.

Here's the split method:

```
public static <T, T1 extends Collection<T>, T2 extends Collection<T>>
    Tuple2<T1, T2> split(final Collection<T> coll,
                         final FilterDelegate<T> filterDelegate,
                         final FilterReturnDelegate<T1> truthyDelegate1,
                         final FilterReturnDelegate<T2> falsyDelegate2) {
    final Collection<T> t1 = truthyDelegate1.createReturnCollection();
    final Collection<T> t2 = falsyDelegate2.createReturnCollection();

    for (final T item : coll) {
        if (filterDelegate.filter(item)) {
            t1.add(item);
        } else {
            t2.add(item);
        }
    }

    final Tuple2<T1, T2> retval = new Tuple2<T1, T2>();
    retval.setItem1(t1);
    retval.setItem2(t2);

    return retval;
}
```

Here's the Tuple2 class. It's a simple generic-aware wrapper of heterogeneous objects.

```
public final class Tuple2<T1, T2> {

    private T1 _item1;

    private T2 _item2;

    public Tuple2() {
    }

    public Tuple2(final T1 item1, final T2 item2) {
        _item1 = item1;
        _item2 = item2;
    }

    public T1 getItem1() {
        return _item1;
    }

    public T2 getItem2() {
        return _item2;
    }

    public void setItem1(final T1 item1) {
        _item1 = item1;
    }

    public void setItem2(final T2 item2) {
        _item2 = item2;
    }

}
```

FilterDelegate:

```
public interface FilterDelegate<T> {

    /**
     *
     * @param item The item to be filtered.
     * @return true if the item should be retained. false if the item should be
     */
    boolean filter(T item);

}
```

FilterReturnDelegate:

```
public interface FilterReturnDelegate<R extends Collection<?>> {

    R createReturnCollection();

}
```

However, the above split method doesn't even compile. Javac is complaining on the lines

```
retval.setItems(t1); retval.setItems(t2);
```

that `"The method setItem1(T1) in the type Tuple2<T1,T2> is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<T>)"`.

Wondering what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Consider just using `Iterables.filter()` from Guava (http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) and skip dealing with all this.

In your case, you'd use both `Iterables.filter(c, p)` and `Iterables.filter(c, Predicates.not(p))` to get both subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `t1` and `t2` should be of type `T1` and `T2`:

```
final T1 t1 = truthyDelegate1.createReturnCollection();
final T2 t2 = falsyDelegate2.createReturnCollection();
```

`Collection<T>` isn't a subtype of `T1`, so `setItem(t1)` would fail.